# Error using Android SDK after running brew install android-sdk

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, homebrew, react-native

I ran brew install android-sdk, then added it to my .bashrc file

Then when I run react-native run-android in a brand new react-native project, I get the following error

```
$ react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /usr/local/opt/android-sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info                                                                or                                                               --debug                                                            option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.043 secs
Could not install the app on the device, see the error above.
```

Is there some problem or something I'm supposed to do to fix this?

This is the stacktrace

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:487)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:85)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: /usr/local/opt/android-sdk
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.getTargetInfo(DefaultSdkLoader.java:88)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:89)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.groovy:507)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.groovy:455)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:415)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders$2.call(SpanRecorders.groovy:52)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.groovy:54)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:414)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be  API 23 is not installed. 
Go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager and check if Marshmallow  (API 23) is installed.

Hope this helps